# Parsing memory dump (looking for a more elegant solution)

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to parse the output of the s51 simulator using a bash script and sed. In a first step I want one single string containing all the bytes in hexadecimal form. The output of the simulator looks like this. The real output can be much longer, up to 64k.

```
0x0000 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 ........
0x0008 18 19 00 00 00 00 00 00 ........
0x0010 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ........
0x0018 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ........
0x0020 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ........
0x0028 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ........
0x0030 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ........
timer #0("time") ON: 0.001085 sec (13020 clks)
timer #0("isr") ON,ISR: 0 sec (0 clks)
timer #0("idle") ON,ISR: 0 sec (0 clks)
```

My code to parse is the following:

```
sed -e ':loop' -e 's/\s\([0-9a-f]\{1\}\)\([0-9a-f]\{1\}\)/\2\1/g' -e 't loop' -n -e 's/.*\(0x[0-9a-f]\{4\}\)\([0-9a-f]\{16\}\).*/\2/p' | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g'
```

The first 3 parts swap the two digits of each byte and removes the space. The 4th part removes the other lines and the address and ascii representation. The last part removes the connects the lines.

This outputs a string likes this:

```
01112131415161718190000000....
```

I was wondering what I could do better.

Comment: Is the current output correct and you just want to simplify the method, or are you trying to get different output?

Comment: The current output is correct. I just want to simplify the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^0x\S\{4\}\(\( \S\S\)\{8\}\).*/{s//\1/;H};$!d;x;s/\n//g;s/ \(.\)\(.\)/\2\1/g' file
```

or (at a pinch):

```
sed -r '/^0x....(( ..){8}).*/{s//\1/;H};$!d;x;s/\n//g;s/ (.)(.)/\2\1/g' file
```

Comment: +1 But perhaps consider using the `-r` flag to make things more elegant/readable? I'm referring to all of those escaped parentheses.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I still have a question about the following statement `$!d;x;`. How does it work?

Comment: `$!d` means "if this is not the last line, delete the contents of the pattern space and return to the beginning of the script".  This means that everything after that will only be executed once, after the entire file has been processed.  `x` means "swap the hold and pattern spaces", and at that point the hold space has all of the byte lines in them.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following should be equivalent:

```
sed -n -e '/^0x[0-9a-f]\{4\}/H' -e '${x;s/\n\S*//g;s/\s\.\.*//g;s/\s\([0-9a-f]\)\([0-9a-f]\)/\2\1/g;p}'
```

Or if your version of `sed` doesn't support separating commands with `;`:

```
sed -n -e '/^0x[0-9a-f]\{4\}/H' -e '${x
s/\n\S*//g
s/\s\.\.*//g
s/\s\([0-9a-f]\)\([0-9a-f]\)/\2\1/g
p
}'
```

This works by adding each byte line to the hold space, and then when we get to the last line of the file swap the hold and pattern spaces to process them all at once.  Then the steps are to remove the newlines and address from beginning of each line, remove the trailing dots (maybe this isn't actually necessary, depending on actual output), and finally swap the digits of each byte and print.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of Linux you are running, there are tools like `od` or `hexdump` that can help with this. `hexdump` is even highly configurable with a sort of mini-script language to control how many bytes get formatted in what way and so on...

Answer (score 0):

One way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk '/^0x/ { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) { gsub(/[^0-9]/,"", $i); line=line $i } } END { printf "%s\n", substr(line,2) }' file.txt
```